# Information Not Being Shown Inline

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to put divs side by side, but it's not working.  One is inline, and the next one is down a little bit and a little bit to the right.

My code:

```
.FifteenInfo {
  display: inline;
  margin-top: 50px;
  height: auto;
  padding-right: 75px;
  float: left;
}
.FourtyInfo {
  display: inline;
  margin-top: 50px;
  height: auto;
  padding-right: 75px;
}
.SixtyInfo {
  display: inline;
  margin-top: 50px;
  height: auto;
  padding-right: 75px;
}
.Package {
  padding-left:70px;
  margin-top: 15px;
}
.monthlyPrice {
  padding-left:55px;
  font-size:52px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #277FD8;
}
.differentbandwidth {
  margin-left: 30px;
  display: inline;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #277FD8;
  border-width: 3px;
  border-radius: 8px;
}
.border {
  border-left: thick solid #277FD8;
  display: inline;
  float: right;
}
.FifteenSpecs {
  display: inline;
  float: right;
}

    <div class="FifteenInfo">
      <h1 class="Package">Cable 15</h1>
      <h3 class="monthlyPrice">\$39.99</h3>
      <h3 class="differentbandwidth">\$69.99 Unlimited</h3>
      <div class="FifteenSpecs border">
        <h1>Cable 156666666666666666666666</h1>
        <h3>\$39.99</h3>
        <h3>\$69.99 Unlimited</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Here's my image of the issue:

[image]

I'm completely lost, I've tried inline, and inline-block display times and they don't work.

So then I watched a couple of YouTube videos to brush up on display properties but it didn't work.

Comment: @JonathanLam I have tried that, to no avail.

Comment: have you tried adding an `!important` tag next to the elements you want to be displayed inline?

Comment: Which elements are you trying to display inline? It's difficult to tell from the picture.

Comment: @JonathanLam FifteenSpecs, border, and FifteenInfo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned in your comment that you wanted to make `.FifteenSpecs.border` display next to (inline with) `.FifteenInfo`.

The main problem then is simply that you have your `.FifteenSpecs` div *inside* your `.FifteenInfo` one, and hence it is displaying *inside* `.FifteenInfo`. Simply move it outside, like so:

```css
body, html {
  min-width: 1000px;
}

.FifteenInfo {
  display: inline-block;
  height: auto;
  background-color: green;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.monthlyPrice {
  font-size:52px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #277FD8;
}
.differentbandwidth {
  text-align: center;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #277FD8;
  border-width: 3px;
  border-radius: 8px;
}
.FifteenSpecs {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: red;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="FifteenInfo">
  <h1 class="Package">Cable 15</h1>
  <h3 class="monthlyPrice">\$39.99</h3>
  <h3 class="differentbandwidth">\$69.99 Unlimited</h3>
</div>
<div class="FifteenSpecs border">
  <h1>Cable 156666666666666666666666</h1>
  <h3>\$39.99</h3>
  <h3>\$69.99 Unlimited</h3>
</div>
```

Some other things I changed in your code:

- Changed `inline` to `inline-block` so that it retains the box model
- Removed all the `padding`, `margin`: this really cluttered it up
- Removed `float`s: `inline-block` will already make it "float" left.
- Added `vertical-align: top` to make the top of the divs line up (as opposed to the bottom)